# (VNC) port opening issue on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, port, port-forwarding, vnc

I want to be able to access my pc with VNC from a remote location.
Because my pc is behind a router (TP-Link WR841N) with NAT enabled, I've forwarded the the required port (5900) to my pc's local IP-adress.

However if I try to connect with the VNC server from outside my local network, it will time out. The port appears closed as well via services like http://www.canyouseeme.org

### Things I've tried:

- I've added allow-rules to both the windows firewall (which is disabled) and comodo antivirus (which is enabled), but this doesn't seem to help.
- I've also tried setting it all up for a slightly different port (5901)
- Finally I've tried this all with both TightVNC and RealVNC.

### Other things of note:

- I've tried enabling VPN as well and have run into the same issue, but I haven't quite tested that as extensively as with VNC.
- I have another pc running Ubuntu in the same local network which ***is*** accessible with VNC, I've forwarded port 5904 on my router to 5900 to that pc's local IP (this shouldn't interfere right?).

Does anyone know something else I can try or where I maybe messed up?

Comment: So VNC port is working fine within your local network but not externally? Sounds like the router isn't forwarding the port. One thing you could try is set the PC IP as the DMZ on your router. Which will open your PC to the WAN. This way you could do a quick test to see whether the router is forwarding the traffic or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I enable DMZ it works. But I'm using the same forwarding settings (aside from the actual port numbers) for my Ubuntu server which does accept external VNC connections, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong with the forwarding.

Comment: Are you sure your router is not blocking ports? Also consider that some ISP's block incoming syn traffic (they don't want people running services from their home internet connection for obvious reasons).

Comment: Would you mind posting a picture of your router's NAT settings?

Comment: I'm not allowed to add it to my post yet (not enough reputation) but here's a link: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/f4c3p/8

Comment: Have you noticed that you're redirecting 5901 to 59**01**, instead of **00**? Is it intentional?

Comment: @Witts Oh, so it worked even after you disable DMZ and rebooted the router? Probably just something wrong with the cache and your router just needed a reboot to apply the changes. Glad it is resolved. But you could always update the firmware of your router if you have any more problems.

Comment: Yes it's resolved, but I had rebooted the router before, so it's a bit odd it suddenly works. Regardless, I'm glad it does and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Following a suggestion by [Ibanz](https://superuser.com/users/167485/lbanz), the problem is resolved by enabling and disabling DMZ.

Things seem to be working permanently now after having DMZ enabled. I've since already disabled it and also rebooted the router to make sure it wasn't secretly still working that way.